# How to design Swift Playgrounds ipad app to control a car over Bluetooth LE

Tags: ipad, bluetooth-lowenergy, swift-playground

I am unsure on how to even start. I only have swift playgrounds on the ipad (no Mac)

I think the app will have 2 sliders, one for the left wheel speed, the other for right wheel speed.
On startup (and if it loses contact) I need to 'connect' to my car over BLE, then I'd use BLE to update it's wheel speeds based on the values of the sliders.

I'm just unsure how to go about it (BluetoothCore, PlaygroundsBluetooth, SwiftUI, UIKit etc.)

I think the app should be fairly simple, so can I do it all in one file? What about bluetooth permissions?

Does anyone know of a good Swift Playgrounds BLE app example?

Comment: The most important thing you will need is specifications from your car's BLE protocol. I'm not familiar with any standard BLE protocol for controlling RC cars (I'm assuming this is an RC car), so this would typically be a custom protocol provided by the manufacturer, unless you're designing your own control hardware. (If you're interested in that, see https://github.com/drme/ble-rc for some interesting examples.) Beyond that, PlaygroundsBluetooth is likely the tool you want. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/playgroundbluetooth/connecting_to_bluetooth_peripherals_in_swift_playgrounds

Comment: Thanks Rob. I have all the BLE details. Just a single service with 2 characteristics (leftSpeed and rightSpeed, both 0-100). What I don't know is how to even start in SwiftPlaygrounds on the iPad. This example, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/playgroundbluetooth/connecting_to_bluetooth_peripherals_in_swift_playgrounds, shows some lines of code to use, but not what file to put them in, or how that code links to a 'view'

Comment: I don't know of any full tutorials on this, and the Stack Overflow Q&A format generally isn't great for that kind of step-by-step tutorial (though someone might write one up; you never know). Usually you'll adapt from more general samples that aren't Playgrounds, such as Apple's main example code: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/transferring_data_between_bluetooth_low_energy_devices/